# My pass-by-reference isn't doing what it should be doing

Tags: c#, pointers, pass-by-reference

I'm scratching my head here... I have a large program which I've written in C# and there is a small bug in it, which makes absolutely no sense to me.

Very quick background:

I have a class called `CompoundSet` which contains a `DataSet` (not `System.Data.DataSet`, it's my own defined class) which is defined like this:

```
public class CompoundSet
{
  private DataSet dataSet;
  public  DataSet { get { return dataSet; } }

  //...
}
```

`compountSet` is a local member in my main workflow class, and I launch a data editor window like this:

```
DataWindow dw = new DataWindow(compoundSet.DataSet);
```

The constructor for the `DataWindow` is like this:

```
public DataWindow(DataSet dataSet)
{
  // ...

  this.dataSet = dataSet;
}
```

and the DataWindow lists the contents of the `DataSet` in various GUI controls.

That window shows what's currently in the DataSet. The user can modify the data as they wish. When they close `dw`, the changes to the data SHOULD be in the `CompoundSet` since we're only passing pointers. The `DataSet` in `compoundSet` and the `DataSet` in `dw` SHOULD be the same however it isn't.

If I set a breakpoint in the `DataWindow` class in the close event, I can see that the local `dw.dataSet` and the `WorkFlow.compoundSet.DataSet` do not have the same information.

Given that I have passed a pointer to `compoundSet.DataSet` to the `DataWindow` class in the constructor, and I have nowhere used a `new` keyword in `DataWindow`, this doesn't make any sense to me?

Why is my `compoundSet.DataSet` different to my `dw.dataSet`?

**Edit**: I have tried creating a `DataWindow` like this:

```
DataSet ds = compoundSet.DataSet;
DataWindow dw = new DataWindow(ds);
dw.ShowDialog(this); // breakpoint on dw.FormClosing shows the dataset has new data
return; // breakpoint here shows ds is different from dw.dataSet
```

Comment: By chance, is `DataSet` a struct ?

Comment: @J.N. Absolutely not :) I wish it were that simple...

Comment: Some code where you actually set new items to your DataSet would be interesting. Are you just modifying DataSet's underlying properties or the DataSet object itself?

Comment: Does `CompoundSet` ever change its `dataSet` member? Also, if you set a breakpoint right after the `DataWindow` constructor (or even better, inside it and single step), are they the same?

Comment: @Ozzah : sorry, I had to check ;) worth mentioning in your question I guess.

Comment: @parkovski No, it never changes. If I set a breakpoint in the constructor then I can see that they contain the same information, but I can't check if they're pointing at the same memory (or rather, I don't know how to do that in VS2010...)

Comment: I found the problem, and I've just fixed and tested it. I had unknowingly reassigned the local `dataSet` variable in my `DataWindow` class in a function which imports from Excel. I've fixed the code so it copies the information element-by-element and it's working as expected now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your tags are a little off (because your terminology is a little bit off) but your understanding of the concepts is correct. The code you have posted is not the source of the problem.

Specifically: you are not passing by reference, you are passing a reference type.  Because it's a reference type, you're not passing the object itself, but a reference to the object (not a "pointer" -- yes, the reference is implemented as a pointer, but that's an implementation detail, and the word "pointer" has a specific, different meaning in c#).  Because you haven't used the "ref" keyword, you're passing that reference by value (but this may not be relevant to your problem).

I would guess that there's some binding problem causing the changes in the ui not to be transmitted to the dataSet object.  But according to the code you've posted, the DataWindow and the CompoundSet should indeed be working with the same object.

It's also possible that you're reassigning the dataSet variable in the elided code, and expecting that reassignment to apply to the compoundSet.DataSet property, but your question implies that this is not the case.

Comment: Re: your 2nd last paragraph, there is no binding problem. As I said, a breakpoint in the `DataWindow` close event shows that the local `DataSet` instance has accepted the changes. Those changes simply aren't reflected in the main window as they should be. Re: your last paragraph, I don't think I have reassigned the local variable, but I am checking my code now. Unfortunately this is one of my largest classes :\

Comment: *sigh*... I found the problem. I did, in fact, unknowingly reassign it somewhere deep in the code. There is a button to import some data from Excel and that returned an entirely new `DataSet`.

Comment: @Ozzah: Looks like you found the problem--redeclaration. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're using the [ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) keyword. Depending on the situation you can end up with duplicated objects instead of a reference to that object (which is what you're seeing). To avoid this, `ref` forces the object to pass by reference insuring you're viewing (and modifying) the same object.

Comment: I have never before observed behaviour where a pass-by-reference will pass a duplicated object instead of a reference to the object I intend to pass. In any case, I have added `ref` and my symptoms are unchanged. But thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: It's not so much that it starts off as a duplication. Typically something that's invoked ends up causing it to duplicate. Basically, it starts off as a copy of the pointer which allows you to edit the object freely. However, if you were to re-delcare it you're actually working with a new object, not re-assinging the original object--if that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, if I were to re-declare it then I would be dealing with a different object of course... but I have not re-declared it anywhere as far as I can see. Maybe it's time to get the fine-tooth comb out.

Comment: You don't need the `ref` keyword in this case. I don't really think [tag:pass-by-reference] is applicable here either - you're passing references, but by value.